# One TableViewController, multiple segue actions and returns

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Before I start, I must point to the usual disclaimer: I am new to Objective-C and Xcode and therefore my question might be stupid - apologies in advance. But here we go:

I have three different arrays:

```
NSArray *parameter_array_1 = @[1,2,3,4]
NSArray *parameter_array_2 @[a,b,c,d]
NSArray *parameter_array_3 = @[1a,2b,3c,4d]
```

From the root table view controller I want to segue into a table view controller showing each array but only once at a time. My problem is that I want to use only one table view controller (and not three different ones) but once I call the delegate to return the selected value I have no way to identify the return array.

I came up with a pretty ugly solution but I wanted to hear other thoughts and suggestions.

Step 1: at prepareForSegue I set an identifier in both the root and destination VC

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
        {
            if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSelection"] )
                {
                    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
                    PTOptionViewController *targetVC = [segue destinationViewController];
                    targetVC.delegate = self;

                    if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:SEGUE_ARRAY_1])
                    {
                        targetVC.identifier = SEGUE_ARRAY_1;
                        targetVC.array1 = self.array1;
                    }
                    if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:SEGUE_ARRAY_2])
                    {
                        targetVC.identifier = SEGUE_ARRAY_2;
                        targetVC.array2 = self.array2;
                    }
                    if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:SEGUE_ARRAY_3])
                    {
                        targetVC.identifier = SEGUE_ARRAY_3;
                        targetVC.array3 = self.array3;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Step 2:

In the destination tableview controller I use the same identifier to determine the delegate call back method and done

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.identifier isEqual:SEGUE_ARRAY_1]) [self.delegate returnArray1Object];
    if ([self.identifier isEqual:SEGUE_ARRAY_2]) [self.delegate returnArray2Object];
    if ([self.identifier isEqual:SEGUE_ARRAY_3]) [self.delegate returnArray3Object];
}
```

Step 3:
In the root view controller I have those return methods which then allow me to take individual actions based on return.

My problem: I am a newbie but even for me this seems very clunky and cumbersome. It might work for two or three parameters but doesn't scale and is prone to errors. But is there an alternative? I don't want to create a new table view controller and segue for each parameter?

Is there a way to pass data to a table view controller and capture the return value but make the table view controller abstract enough that I can call it for different arrays? Maybe there is a way to determine the delegate method based on the sender?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better of using an array of arrays to hold your data:

```
NSArray *parameters = @[@[1,2,3,4],
                        @[a,b,c,d],
                        @[1a,2b,3c,4d]
                     ];
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                         didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSelection" sender:self];
}
```

**prepareForSegue**

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSelection"]){
        PTOptionViewController * targetVC = 
                     (PTOptionViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        targetVC.dataArray =parameters[indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok great for the tip. I initially thought about it but then it seemed odd to me handing over all of the data just to show a subset. But if that the recommended way then cool...

Comment: @user3757285 actually it does not pass all of the data, notice when preparing the segue, `parameters[indexPath.row];` gets the subset data at that index of the multidimensional array

Comment: Thanks - I just noticed. Thanks much for the advice - I am fighting my way through Xcode :)

Comment: I would have one more question if you don't mind. Currently I used multiple delegate methods in order to assign the returned parameter value to a different object. With this new approach I can see how it helps with not having to create my segue mess but how would I identify the return array in the delegate method? I don't think I can pass the Indexpath back to the root controller? Thanks